# Keycloak get all users returns 403 and message "unknown_error"

Tags: keycloak

I'm using version 21.1.1 of Keycloak and I'm trying to list the users from the endpoint `https://{myDomain}/admin/realms/{myRealm}/users`, I pass the Authorization header with the bearer token obtained, but I always get I see a 403 error - `unknown_error` in the tests I do through Insomnia, does anyone have any idea what it could be?

Comment: What do the browser developer tools tell you?  Keyclock is pretty verbose on what isn't working.

Comment: I'm triggering the request through Insomnia...

Comment: Ok, but what is the response?  You can still see the responses from Keycloak - perhaps even easier than a browser.

Comment: The only answer I have is this:

`{ "error": "unknown_error" }`